# unhandled promise rejection warning - couldn't store into database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, promise

Data comming from req is store in Comment collection but it is not store in Product collection and i'll get an error message

```
app.post("/products/:id/comments", function(req, res) {
//lookup campground using ID
Product.findById(req.params.id, function(err, product) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/products");
    } else {
        Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("aaaaaa");
                product.comments.push(comment);
                console.log("bbbbbb");
                product.save();
                console.log("cccccc");
                res.redirect('/products/' + product._id);
            }
        });
    }
});});
```

and following is Product

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
img: String,
price: Number,
desc: String,
comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Comment"
}],
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
}});module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

and this is Comment Schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: String
});module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

and i got following output :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS0da.png)

so it's store in commentSchema but it's not store in product.comments and when i run site that also redirect to products/:id, what i'm missing to store comment into database ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don’t pass a callback function to **save()** then it will return a promise.

Therefore, you are getting the error as you have not added a **catch**.

Try passing a callback to **save()**:

```
// ...

product.save(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
  }
  console.log("cccccc");
  res.redirect('/products/' + product._id);
})
```

Comment: if i apply callback then i'll get another err which is following...https://www.datafilehost.com/d/3b62cfbc